# `next.js` api is resolved before promise fullfill?

Tags: promise, next.js

I want to achieve something like this:

1. call my website url `https://mywebsite/api/something`
2. then my `next.js` website api will call external api
3. get external api data
4. update external api data to mongodb database one by one
5. then return respose it's status.

Below code is working correctly correctly. data is updating on mongodb but when I request to my api url it respond me very quickly then it updates data in database.
But I want to first update data in database and then respond me

No matter how much time its take.
Below is my code

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    async function updateServer(){
        return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject){
            const statusArray = [];
            const apiUrl = `https://example.com/api`;
            const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }});
            const newsResults = await response.json();
            const articles = await newsResults["articles"];

            for (let i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
                const article = articles[i];
                try {
             
                    insertionData["title"] = article["title"];
                    insertionData["description"] = article["description"];

                    MongoClient.connect(mongoUri, async function (error, db) {
                        if (error) throw error;
                        const articlesCollection = db.db("database").collection("collectionname");
                        const customQuery = { url: article["url"] };
                        const customUpdate = { $set: insertionData };
                        const customOptions = { upsert: true };
                        const status = await articlesCollection.updateOne(customQuery,customUpdate,customOptions);
                        statusArray.push(status);
                        db.close();
                    });
                } catch (error) {console.log(error);}
            }


            if(statusArray){
                console.log("success", statusArray.length);
                resolve(statusArray);
            } else {
                console.log("error");
                reject("reject because no statusArray");
            }
        });
    }

    updateServer().then(
        function(statusArray){
            return res.status(200).json({ "response": "success","statusArray":statusArray }).end();
        }
    ).catch(
        function(error){
            return res.status(500).json({ "response": "error", }).end();
        }
    );

}
```

How to achieve that?

Any suggestions are always welcome!

Comment: I got a suggestion, but it doesn't solve your problem: forget about promises and use only async/await

Comment: It tried async await it doesn't worked What is your suggestion

Comment: Nevermind. Anyway I think that the problem may be that `MongoClient.connect` is async and you are not awaiting for it. But I'm just guessing, you need to check the docs. By the way, connecting inside a loop is probably a waste of resources. You should move the connection outside of the loop.

Comment: okay I am trying it outside of loop using `updateMany`

Comment: @anotherOne How to use `updateMany` first check if url  is present or not if present then update else insert. I  can use it in updateOne in filter I can add {url: "https://url.com"}
but when I am using updateMany how to check array of urls ["https://url1.com", "https://url2.com"]

Comment: I don't know. Try to check the docs https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/

Comment: Add a return statement, i.e. `return updateServer().then(...).catch(...);`